# According to Stewart Calculus Early Transcendentals 5th Edition on page 140, in example 5, how does he simplify this problem?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

In Stewart's *Calculus: Early Transcendentals* 5th Edition on page 140, in example 5, how does 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x}{x}}$$

simplify to

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1 + \dfrac{1}{x^2}} + 1}$$

I understand how he simplifies $\frac{x}{x}$ to 1 but how does he simplify $\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Observe that, for $x>0$,
$$\large\sqrt{x^2+1\strut}=\sqrt{x^2(1+\tfrac{1}{x^2})}=\sqrt{x^2\strut} \;\cdot\;\sqrt{1+\tfrac{1}{x^2}}=x\;\cdot\;\sqrt{1+\tfrac{1}{x^2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since you are calculating the limit at $x\to\infty$ you may assume that $x>0$. Then
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}x=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2}}+\frac xx=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}}+1=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1$$

Comment: So the x in the denominator can be the square root of (x^2)?

Comment: Yes. If $x\ge 0$ then $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ and if $x<0$ then $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$. In other "words", $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Answer (score -2):

$$
\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2} + \frac 1 {x^2}} = \cdots
$$

$\frac{\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x}{x}\right)}$ is exactly the same thing as $\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}$.  To get that just multiply the numerator and the denominator by $x$.  Then:
$$
0 < \frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}<\frac 1 {2x} \to 0 \text{ as } x\to\infty.
$$